# scheme - dynamic scope - why this is the return value?

Tags: dynamic, scheme

why under dynamic scope this code will return error for "g not defined"?
when running ((ff) 5), at some point g will get a value (the f lambda) and will be inserted into the runtime stack.

```
(
let ((f (lambda (g)
  (lambda (n)
   (if (zero? n)
    1
    (* n ((g g) (- n 1))))))))
((f f) 5)
)
```

Comment: Scheme is a lexically scoped language. Which language is this?

Answer (score 1):

With dynamic scope you don't have closures. Eg.

```
(define val #f)

(define (get-val val)
  (lambda ()
    val))

(define getter (get-val 5))
(getter) ; => #f
```

With lexical scope `val` from `get-val` lives in the returned procedure as a free variable and would return `5`, but in dynamic scope it stopped existing right ather the proceudre was returned. The `val` referred in the procedure is whatever bound `val` in the dynamic scope. Eg.

```
(let ((val 10))
  (getter)) ; ==> 10
```

So `val` from the `let` became the closest binding with that name ad `getter` returned that.

Comment: thanks! about your last example - is it under dynamic scope? if so, and according to what I understand from your explanation, isn't it closure and if so the val not exist when running (getter)?

Comment: @gdgd It's dynamic. In lexical scope both times you would get `5` since `val` in the `let` before the call doesn't affect `val` in the returned procdure, but in dynamic scope every binding in the nested calls are targets. It is very easy to implement, but it is very hard to find bugs. The very first  lisp paper had an example of a higher order procedure that would fail because of the same named variables would catch the wrong variable.